# Trouble with preventing mod_rewrite on a sub folder

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to set up a small Wordpress install on a sub folder for a client. Their existing site is very small but WP is to be for something separate, so it's not replacing their existing site, it's just to run a separate blog.

Their .htaccess file is as follows

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Their existing site puts everything through the index.php so index.php?contact becomes /contact/

I am trying to put a wordpress install into a subfolder called "blog". However, every time I try to run the installer, I just get the home page. Accessing files like images works fine, but trying to access any .php just loads the home page. I've tried `RewriteEngine Off` just to test, but it doesn't work.

If I take the above code out, it works (but breaks the site).

My goal is to just have a subdirectory be ignored from the rewrite rules. Any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this condition right before the rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, weirdly. I've amended the .htaccess and added that above the last line, but makes no difference unfortunately.